# OSX pkg uninstaller - is it possible to change the "Install" text in the title bar?

Tags: macos, pkgbuild, pkg-file

I created a separated uninstaller to:

- stop service
- rm plist file
- rm datadir
- ...

Problem: in the title bar, it's "Install ..." and the welcome title is "Welcome to ... installer".

Is it possible to change the title bar to "Uninstall ..." and the welcome title to "Welcome to ... uninstaller"?

[image]